# How to transpose data in R without losing information?

Tags: r

I am looking to transpose my data set.

Pretext: As QIIME2 outputs so that 'Feature.ID' (essentially bacterial species) are rows and Sites are columns, with abundance in the cell values. As many R packages such as Biodiversity require the sites are rows and species as columns, I am looking to transpose my data.

```
library(tidyverse)

Ftable <- read_tsv('table.feature-table_biom.txt', col_names = TRUE, skip = 1) #opens my QIIME2 file, removing the top line 

names(Ftable)[names(Ftable)=="#OTU ID"] <- "Feature.ID" #Renames the species column

Ftable <- cbind(Ftable, "observation"=1:nrow(Ftable)) #adds an indexing column 'observation' so that I can later remove the column containing the species names as they are complex and I do not wish to type them out

Ftable <- Ftable %>% select(observation, everything()) #Moves observation to the front

OtuOb <- Ftable

OtuOb <- as.tibble(OtuOb) 

write_tsv(OtuOb, "OtuToObservationReference.tsv") #These 3 lines save a reference so I can look to see which observations align to which species

Ftable <- Ftable[,-2] #removes 'Feature.ID' column so that the observation column shows the species

Ftable <- t(Ftable) #I have been trying to get this to work but it doesnt

Ftable <- as.tibble(Ftable) 

write_tsv(Ftable, "Ftable.tsv")
```

When transposing it removes the sample references (along the top in the original) which means I have no way of seeing how they match up to the abundancies of that species.

[Small sample of my data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQPwmWS_p_woDiqjGTeUEXChB0g0-ZbSxRNzzTevGb3TkAQaCx8LoVHm2LtxIzIriRmaLUlrKawiPZ2/pubhtml)

Comment: I think there is some confusion (probably on my end), I want the original row names to appear as column names in my transposed data

Comment: Assign your row names to an object (e.g. `Ftable_rownames <- rownames(Ftable)`, transpose, then assign the stored vector to the colnames (`colnames(Ftable) <- Ftable_rownames`)

Comment: okay I'm very sorry I seem to have got muddled. Basically the other way around, retain the column names, and assign them to the appropriate row.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you certainly pointed me in the right direction! How do I 'approve' your answer? (sorry new here)

Comment: I've posted an answer below. Press the green ✓ to mark the question closed/complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before transposing, assign your row names to an object, do the transpose, then assign the stored row names to the new column names:

```
Ftable_rownames <- rownames(Ftable)

# transpose
Ftable <- t(Ftable)

# assign names from the stored object
colnames(Ftable) <- Ftable_rownames
```